# Vscode does not autocomplete on functional Enum in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, enums, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to create an Enum class using the functional API and wanted to have autocompletion once I call the enum class. However vscode does not seem to work if the Enum is created using a temp variable for the elements.
Using python 3.10.12 and
VSCode:
1.81.1
6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
x64

```py
from enum import Enum
class Color(str, Enum):
    AMARILLO = "yellow"


ColorFunctional = Enum("ColorFunctional", {"RED": "red", "BLUE": "blue", "AMARILLO": "yellow"}, type=str)

my_dict = {"RED": "red", "BLUE": "blue", "AMARILLO": "yellow"}
ColorFunctionalIndirect = Enum("B", my_dict, type=str)

assert Color.AMARILLO == "yellow" # -> This autocompletes and higlights!
assert ColorFunctional.AMARILLO == "yellow" # This just autocompletes (no highligthing)
assert ColorFunctionalIndirect.AMARILLO == "yellow" # This neither autocompletes nor highlights
```

[image]

[image]

I would expect to at least have the same autocompletion behaviour of `ColorFunctional` in `ColorFunctionalIndirect` even if the highlighting does not work.

Comment: the type-checking in Python is based on static analysis, by using a variable instead of a literal value you have created a type which can only be resolved at runtime

Answer (score 0):

**GitHub once replied:**

- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4333#issuecomment-1542920065

> pylance is a static analyzer, so unfortunately none of the dynamic behavior will be supported.

**Explanation in vscode official documentation:**

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense

> Pylance is based on Microsoft’s [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) static type checking tool, leveraging [type stubs](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html) (`.pyi` files) and lazy type inferencing to provide a highly-performant development experience.